# Rotation on a Complex Plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be complex numbers. Let $a_1$ be the image of $a$ when it is rotated $90^\circ$ clockwise around $b$. Let $a_2$ be the image of $a_1$ when it is rotated $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise around $c$.

[image]

Then $a_2$ can be written in the form
$$a_2 = pa + qb + rc$$
for some complex numbers $p$, $q$, and $r$. Find $p^2 + q^2 + r^2$.

I used the basic formula of $(z-w)e^{i\theta}+w$ to rotate, but it didn't seem to help me at all. Could someone give a constructive solution to the problem? Thank you!

Comment: `I used the basic formula` Rotations of $90^\circ$ correspond to $\,\theta = \pm \pi /2\,$ thus $\,e^{i\theta}=\pm i\,$. `didn't seem to help me at all` What have you got, which didn't help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotating $\pi/2$ clockwise about $0$ is $z\mapsto -iz$.
Rotating $\pi/2$ clockwise about $b$ is translating through $-b$,
rotating clockwise $\pi/2$ about $0$ and then translating back through $b$,
that is $z\mapsto -i(z-b)+b$.

Similarly rotating anticlockwise $\pi/2$ about $c$ is $z\mapsto i(z-c)+c$.
Applying these in turn to $a$ gives
$$i(-i(a-b)+b-c)+c.$$
Now simplify...

Comment: $i(-i(a-b)+b-c)+c = i(-ia+ib+b-c)+c = a-b+bi-ci+c = 1a + (-1+i)b + (1-i)c$

Comment: $(-1+i)^2+ (1-i)^2+1 = 1-4i$ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Think vectors . . .

\begin{align*}
a_1&=b-i(a-b)&&\text{[Since $e^{i(-\pi/2)} = -i$]}\\[4pt]
&=-ia+(1+i)b\\[8pt]
a_2&=c+i(a_1-c)&&\text{[Since $e^{i(\pi/2)} = i$]}\\[4pt]
&=c+i\bigl((-ia+(1+i)b)-c\bigr)\\[4pt]
&=a+(-1+i)b+(1-i)c\\[8pt]
\text{Hence}\;\;p^2 + q^2 + r^2 &= (1)^2 + (-1 + i)^2 + (1 - i)^2 = 1-4i\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\;\;\,$Apologies for my initial (really bad!) errors.

$\qquad\;\;\,$I shouldn't post when I'm too tired to think straight.

$\qquad\;\;\,$In any case, I felt I at least had to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, was (very!) careless -- now fixed.

Comment: indeed it is :D